# Conjugate diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $M$ be the set of matrices that have precisely one entry in each row/column that is nonzero and $D$ be the set of invertible diagonal matrices ( so all entries down the diagonal are nonzero).

Now, I want to show that for each $m \in M$ and $d \in D$ we have $m \cdot d \cdot m^{-1} \in D$.
It is clear that $m^{-1}$ exists, as all matrices in $M$ have full rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use permutation matrices here.

For each $m\in M$, define $p$ the permutation matrix such that $pm$ is diagonal. Then $(pm)^{-1} = m^{-1}p^T$ so $(pm)d(m^{-1}p^T)$ is diagonal (since it is the product of 3 diagonal matrices). Since for any $d\in D, pdp^T=d$ then $mdm^{-1} = pmdm^{-1}p^T$ is diagonal.